# Different `String` function behavior in Chromium and Safari

Tags: javascript

If you run the following code in the browser console, then you get different results in Chromium and Safari.

```js
String(function() { <!--
}).length
```

Chromium returns:

`19`

Safari returns:

`20`

Why?

#### Note 1

Running via the StackOverflow code editor will deliver the same output, regardless of browser, probably due to the various levels of mediation between the raw output and the browser window.

#### Note 2

The `toString` outputs rendered into the console, differ:

Chromium:

```
'function() { \x3C!--\n}'
```

Safari:

```
"function () { <!--
}"
```

#### EDIT

This contains a correction of an earlier version of this question that presented incorrect interpretations of the result.

Comment: Firefox shows 19 :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPCMc.png

Comment: Can you please explain to me what does this code actually do?)

Comment: It is an explicit coercion of a function to a string, followed by a retrieval of the length value associated with the resulting string.

Comment: Just pasting this into the console returns 19 in Edge and Chrome for me.

Comment: Now, as the question has been edited, I'd start by outputing `.toString()` in both cases. The newline could possibly be encoded differently.

Comment: Can you please show us the output of following code without pressing enter, I mean in preview mode? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh4BK.png

Comment: Safari does not have a preview that I can see, but I have added to `toString` renderings to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason here is not the different linebreak symbols, but in fact Safari adds a space before the `()` function parentheses in its syntax. Try this to compare the characters side by side more easily:

```
String(function() {
}).split("")
```

You will see that in Chrome, it will write it as

`function()`

whereas in Safari it becomes

`function ()`.

Comment: Is Safari spec compliant?

Comment: @BenAston I must admit I don't know what the spec says on this type of string creation, I will be curious to learn :) But I would be surprised if the spec requires that the exact syntax you use to write a function needs to be preserved when converting a function to a string. So my guess is that that the browsers (as usual) just love to walk their own ways wherever the spec allows (safari in particular, heh).

Comment: I suspect it is compliant: "Conforming ECMAScript implementations are not required to perform any normalization of source text, or behave as though they were performing normalization of source text.". [Source](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-source-text).

Comment: @BenAston I think this is a more descriptive chapter of function to string. But yes, same conclusion, if I understand it correctly: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-function.prototype.tostring